# Unix/bash. Two for loops in parallel for file names with numbers

Tags: bash, for-loop, unix

I have a directory with many files with similar names like these:

```
file_0.5_1.5_xxxx.txt
file_1.5_2.5_xxxx.txt
file_2.5_3.5_xxxx.txt
file_3.5_4.5_xxxx.txt
...
file_1000.5_1001.5_xxxx.txt
```

Using unix/bash, I want to perform some actions in each of them and then output files with similar names like:

```
file_0.5_1.5_xxxx2.txt
file_1.5_2.5_xxxx2.txt
file_2.5_3.5_xxxx2.txt
file_3.5_4.5_xxxx2.txt
...
file_1000.5_1001.5_xxxx2.txt
```

I am thinking in doing a for loop like this (below), but I am having trouble with the expression "{i+1}". There must be some simple way of doing it, but I am not able to find how:

```
for i in {0..1000}; do
grep house file_${i}.5_${i+1}.5_xxxx.txt > file_${i}.5_${i+1}.5_xxxx2.txt;
done
```

Thank you !

Comment: Are you using that loop on numbers, etc. because you have other files in the directory that you do **not** want changed? Otherwise a simple `for file in *; grep 'house' "$file"...` is all you'd need for that input side.

Comment: Yes @EdMorton, I want to use it only in numbers. Thank you

Comment: And are all those files guaranteed to exist or do we need to test for them existing before grep-ing in  them?

Comment: @EdMorton we need to test for them existing

Comment: Is there any reason not to do `for file in file_[0-9]*.5_[0-9]*.5_xxxx.txt` or `shopt -s extglob; for file in file_+([0-9]).5_+([0-9]).5_xxxx.txt` or similar so we loop on the existing files instead of guessing at which files might exist and then testing whether or not they do?

Comment: @EdMorton that sounds like a good idea

Comment: Ah, I see you already accepted an answer. OK, ask a new question if you need more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use it like this:

```bash
for i in {0..1000}; do
   fn="file_${i}.5_$((i+1)).5_xxxx.txt"
   grep -F 'house' "$fn" > "${fn/.txt/2.txt}"
done
```

Comment: Alternative if xxxx is arbitrary data: `"${fn/.txt/2.txt}"`

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU Parallel:

```
parallel 'do_stuff {} > {.}2.txt' ::: file*.txt
```